# Update the status of a record in mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have following code to update status of a table record

```
public ActionResult Change_State(string ParameterID, string value)
{
    string Updatesubsidary = "UPDATE Table_Name SET Status= '" + value + "' WHERE ID = '" + ParameterID + "'";
    updateQuery(Updatesubsidary);
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

This doesn't have any compile time error or run time error , but table doesn't update,

EDIT:

```
public void updateQuery(string query)
{
    using (SqlConnection connnectionline = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand commandline = new SqlCommand();
        commandline.CommandText = query;
        commandline.Connection = connnectionline;

        connnectionline.Open();
        commandline.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Once I put debug point inside both `Change_State` and `updateQuery` table then thats row getting update ,**

Could you please advise me whats the issue here

Comment: show updateQuery(...)

Comment: paste your updateQuery Method as well

Comment: Before you go any further, you need to read up on [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Shall I update this through `linq` query ?

Comment: Im with @StephenMuecke either use a SP or EntityFramework to get the things done easily and effectively

Comment: @kez yes use linq that's a better option

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
commandline.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have a simple helper class for executing t-sql commands. Check it out [here](https://app.box.com/s/zyl1z4xopx8mu73to0vt169w855a7191)

UPDATE:

Aside from above, please remove this line:

```
connnectionline.Open();
```